# query for jobject child with specific attribute value

Tags: linq, json.net

i need to load xml data into newtonsoft JObject and query for specific name & value nodes...

this is just a simplified sample, the problem is in the last line of code, resultSecondLevel is null even if there is an element child of resultFirstLevel with the ID i'm is looking for...

example:

```
  int idFirst = 2;
            int idSecond = 4;
            string json = string.Empty;
            JObject jFirstLevels = new JObject();

            string xml = "<Root><FirstLevel id=\"1\"><Secondlevel id=\"1\"  value=\"hello11\" /><Secondlevel id=\"2\"  value=\"hello12\" /><Secondlevel id=\"3\"  value=\"hello13\" /></FirstLevel><FirstLevel id=\"2\"><Secondlevel id=\"4\" value=\"hello24\" /></FirstLevel><FirstLevel id=\"3\"><Secondlevel id=\"5\" value=\"hello35\" /><Secondlevel id=\"6\" value=\"hello36\" /><Secondlevel id=\"7\" value=\"hello37\" /></FirstLevel></Root>";

            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);

            XmlNodeList nodeList;
            nodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("Root/FirstLevel");
            if (nodeList != null)
            {
                if (nodeList.Count > 1)
                {
                    JArray jarray = new JArray();

                    foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
                    {
                        json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(node);
                        jarray.Add(JObject.Parse(json));
                    }
                    jFirstLevels["result"] = jarray;
                }
            }

            JObject resultFirstLevel = jFirstLevels["result"].Children<JObject>().FirstOrDefault(x => x["FirstLevel"]["@id"].Value<int>() == idFirst);
            JObject resultSecondLevel = resultFirstLevel.Children<JObject>().FirstOrDefault(x => x["SecondLevel"]["@id"].Value<int>() == idSecond);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you get a list of JProperty in resultFirstLevel.
You need to switch with this code, for instance:

```
JObject resultFirstLevel = jFirstLevels["result"].Children<JObject>().FirstOrDefault(x => x["FirstLevel"]["@id"].Value<int>() == idFirst);
var firstlevelProperty = resultFirstLevel.Children().Cast<JProperty>().Select(x => x.Value);
var resultSecondLevel = firstlevelProperty.FirstOrDefault(x => x["Secondlevel"]["@id"].Value<int>() == idSecond);
```

(Besides there's a typo between the xml you've entered and your test: it's "Secondlevel" with a lower "l")